# Batch file copy does destination file already exist?

Tags: batch-file, rename

Here is the snippet. %%X is the source path. I want to replace the source path with destination path or just remove the source path.

%_DEST%\%%X is not working in this snippet... where it checks to see if the destination file already exists.  What is the proper way to check to see if the destination file exists?

```
call :LOGMSG Copying new jpeg image files
for %%X in (%_SRC%\*.jpeg) do if not exist %_DEST%\%%X (
    xcopy %_SRC%\%%X %_DEST% /defy >>"%run_log%"
    call sd.exe add %%X >>"%run_log%"
)
```

Comment: You have a typo in the title. Please change "Bath" to "Batch"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `~n` in the variable to get rid of the path part. Also, you don't need `%_SRC\%` in the xcopy line:

```
call :LOGMSG Copying new jpeg image files
for %%X in (%_SRC%\*.jpeg) do if not exist %_DEST%\%%~nX (
    xcopy %%X %_DEST% /defy >>"%run_log%"
    call sd.exe add %%X >>"%run_log%"
)
```

Check out `for /?` for explanation and other goodies.